# Get query logs from MySqlConnector in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

How to get the query logs from MySqlConnector (used with Dapper) in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application?

Answer (score 3):

Install [MySqlConnector.Logging.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector.Logging.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/) using NuGet

```
# Core CLI
dotnet add package MySqlConnector.Logging.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
# VS package manager
Install-Package MySqlConnector.Logging.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
```

and set the provider in `Startup.Configure` method:

```
var factory = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
MySqlConnectorLogManager.Provider = new MicrosoftExtensionsLoggingLoggerProvider(factory);
```

**UPDATE** I found out that this causes *The logging provider must be set before any MySqlConnector methods are called* errors when you're running DB queries in a hosted service constructor. This could be fixed by adding it at the end of `Startup.ConfigureServices` instead:

```
var loggerFactory = provider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
MySqlConnectorLogManager.Provider = new MicrosoftExtensionsLoggingLoggerProvider(loggerFactory);
```

### Displaying the logs

To display the logs, it's required to set your log level to debug in `appsettings.json`. I'd recomment the component based approach, because setting everything to debug would result in a massive amount of logs.

For queries, the `TextCommandExecutor` is responsible. We can enable logs for him like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "warning",
      "TextCommandExecutor": "debug"
    }
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
dbug: TextCommandExecutor[0]
      Session1.1 ExecuteBehavior Synchronous CommandText:
                              SELECT varname, value
                              FROM setting
                              WHERE varname IN('bburl', 'recycle_forum', 'maxposts')
```

### Find the component

The component name could be found in two ways:

#### Look into the source code for calls to the logger like this:

```
static readonly IMySqlConnectorLogger Log = MySqlConnectorLogManager.CreateLogger(nameof(TextCommandExecutor));
```

#### Set the default log level for debug (only in small test environments)

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "debug"
    }
  }
}
```

Now you see all logs and find the component after the level like `dbug: TextCommandExecutor[0] ...`.

**Source:** https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/logging/